# Is it correct to use 'wet cold' as a compound adjective?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to use 'such a wet cold weather' in the following sentence?

> It was such a wet cold weather that we could not go out.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some punctuation:

> It was such a wet, cold weather that we could not go out.

You can't really have a 'wet cold' but by adding in the punctuation as above you are describing the weather as 'wet' and 'cold'. Typically, for descriptive writing, I've seen descriptive words come in groups of three - possibly a Shakespearean device?

Comment: As I hit post I had a thought, a 'wet cold' could be used to describe the illness 'a common cold' as in 'I have a wet cold' or 'I have a dry cold'. In this way, you are giving information about the common cold.

Comment: *A ...weather* is not idiomatic.  It should read: *It was such wet cold weather...* No **a** before weather unless you are using weather as an adjective as in *a cold weather front*.